# What's "pressure strip" in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "I'm not going to make a speech，" the Major said, sweeping them with the blank lenses that covered his eyes. "I give my congratulations to the winner among your number, and my acknowledgments of valor to the losers."
>
> He turned to the back of the jeep. There was a living silence. Garraty breathed deep of the spring air. It would be warm. A good day to walk.
>
> The Major turned back to them. He was holding a clipboard. "When I call your name, please step forward and take your number. Then go back to your place until it is time to begin. Do this smartly, please."
>
> "You're in the army now," Olson whispered with a grin, but Garraty ignored it. You couldn't help admiring the Major. Garraty's father, before the Squads took him away, had been fond of calling the Major the rarest and most dangerous monster any nation can produce, a society-supported sociopath. But he had never seen the Major in person.
>
> "Aaronson."
>
> A short, chunky farmboy with a sunburned neck gangled forward, obviously awed by  the Major's presence, and took his large plastic 1. He fixed it to his shirt by the ***pressure strip*** and the Major clapped him on the back.
>
> *The Long Walk*

I googled [pressure strip](https://www.google.com/search?bih=699&biw=1280&hl=zh-CN&ei=TFZGX5C0NYG0mAXGqoT4AQ&q=pressure%20strip&oq=pressure%20strip&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICAAQBxAeEBMyCAgAEAcQHhATMggIABAHEB4QEzIICAAQBxAeEBMyCAgAEAcQHhATMggIABAHEB4QEzIICAAQBxAeEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBggAEB4QE1CZ8AlYmfAJYPDyCWgAcAB4AIABgAKIAYACkgEDMi0xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiQitqS8LjrAhUBGqYKHUYVAR8Q4dUDCA0&uact=5). It doesn't look like something that is used to fix a badge or alike to one's shirt. So I'm rather confused. What's the ***pressure strip*** referring to in this context?

Comment: You really need to give more context to make the cited text comprehensible. I've just had to go to all the trouble of finding the source and figuring out that "Aaronson" must be ***Number 1*** in an alphabetical list of the assembled company. So "his large plastic 1" really does refer to a large plastic "ID badge" consisting of just the digit **1**. In which case obviously the "pressure strip" is the "**sticky back**" by which it can be fixed to clothing, etc.. Which you presumably knew, since you had the benefit of reading all that prior context.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Sorry for having you gone through the trouble of figuring this out.  Why is it called "pressure strip"? There is nothing in the context to figure it out.  I googled it but it doesn't seem to be used for this purpose, which confused me.

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I had no idea what "pressure strip" meant here until I found that full context. At which point it became trivial enough to figure out what it meant. But for what it's worth, you should know that I've just typed in **define "pressure strip"** to Google, and I can't see anything at all in the first two pages of results that gives any relevant definition. So I repeat my original point. You having already read the preceding context were in a far better position to answer your own question than me a native speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica But preceding context doesn't have anything relevant. I can add them later though. Now, it seems that looking for what it truly means is kind of 'nitpicking'.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, I just added few more passages. Just so you know, I just read the book for few pages, so far I haven't seen it's said in any of the previous pages I read.

Comment: I initially read the *[large plastic] **1*** as some kind of OCR error or perhaps "eye-dialect" for ***one** [of some type of thing previously mentioned]*. It took a while for me to realize it was just a numbered "identity badge" in some context where people are being identified by numbers corresponding to alphabetically sorted surnames. You obviously knew that, since you'd just read about the Major saying *When I call your name, please step forward and take your number*.

Comment: btw - the only meaning I knew for "pressure strip" before this was the electronic switch / pressure detector under a rubberized strip in the road just before a set of traffic lights. As a newly-qualified young driver over 50 years ago I once waited over 5 minutes at a traffic light that was stuck on red, late at night in a town centre deserted apart from me and a cop standing by the lights. Eventually  he came over and stamped on the rubber pressure strip behind me. (My car simply hadn't been heavy enough to activate the switching device when I drove up to the junction! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it served to attach a piece of plastic with the numeral "1" on it to his shirt, the pressure strip must have been an area on the plastic that was coated with a pressure-sensitive adhesive.

See this article:
[Wikipedia "pressure-sensitive adhesiive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure-sensitive_adhesive)